# Desktop GUI shows broken visual patches on every boot up

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 20.04, ubuntu-gnome, desktop-icons

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. And I am running a Dual boot system with Windows.

Now whenever I login, in Ubuntu, I get this type of patched screen as in image [image: above]. Now, if I change the background the problem is not there. On, sleep or log out it doesn't repeats. But, if I restart ot reboot again, the same problem exits.

I have tried updating all packages and installing all software updates, but am unable to solve this problem.

My current system information are as follow:

OS Name - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

OS type - 64-bit

GNOME Version - 3.36.3

Windowing System - x11

Also, sometimes the patch appears on top header or Docks. This isn't solved by changing Background too. It gets corrected only when I restart again. This  problem was never in 18.04

Output of
`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

Related just now ( Asked today, exact same OS): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612018/ubuntu-20-04-problems-with-interface-after-installation

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Added the requested information. @Pilot6

Comment: It looks like a bug to me.